# Action is publish still it not display in other account

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Submitted Google Action for review and got an email XXXXXX-8x1f3 was approved and is now in the process of being deployed to Production!.

Still, I can't see action in another user account.

Comment: It takes a day or two to make your google action fully live.

Comment: it was published 15 days ago, can't see action in another user account.

Comment: what is the status of the action.

Comment: Approved - Production - deployed.

Comment: Are there any specific blockers in your action like language or location?

Comment: nope, Got google support reply "we get that your Action is not yet visible in the Google Home App even though it’s already in the Assistant Directory. Not to mention the fact that it’s currently deployed to production as per Actions Console. However, we’d like to let you know that we discussed the issue with our internal team. What you can to resolve the issue is to resubmit your Action for another review. We thank you for your patience and understanding. 
"

Comment: nope, I was talked with google support, I withdraw public action and submitted it. now all are fine.